# Почему пропадает столбец, в котором я выполняю команду drop?

Tags: python, pandas

Я имею датафрейм шириной 2 столбца, и множеством строк, мне нужно удалить лишние наименования в столбце Name.

[image: DataFrame]

```
    new_salez = new_salez.set_index('Name')
new_salezz = new_salez.drop(['Детский ', 'Детский будни', 'Детский будни премиум', 'Детский выходной', 'Итого'], axis = 0)
```

После выполнения этой команды у меня пропадает столбец Name.

```
    new_salezz.Name.unique()
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Name'
```

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Comment: Так вы сами перенесли столбец `Name` в индекс: `new_salez = new_salez.set_index('Name')`. Что у вас во втором столбце и по какому принципу вы хотите удалить "лишние" записи? То, что вы показали - это один столбец (плюс слева индекс ещё). Вам нужны просто уникальные значения столбца `Name`, а индекс не нужен?

Comment: У меня есть различные наименования программ в столбце Name, мне нужно некоторые из них удалить по названию.
Например: мне нужно удалить все строчки, которые содержат "Электронный сертификат безлимит на 1 персону", а все остальные оставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Столбец пропадает, потому что вы сами его переносите в индекс вот этим кодом:

```py
new_salez = new_salez.set_index('Name')
```

Используйте лучше `isin` с отрицанием `~`:

```py
exclude = ['Детский ', 'Детский будни', 'Детский будни премиум', 'Детский выходной', 'Итого']
new_salez = new_salez[~new_salez['Name'].isin(exclude)]
```

Comment: Ого, круто, работает!
Не знал о такой функции, спасибо за разъяснения, благодарен!

Comment: В `Pandas` есть функции практически на все случаи жизни. Постепенно разберётесь. Обычно там любые, даже кажущиеся сложными действия, делаются одной функцией, только нужно знать, какой. )